# Package installed on Angular not working but working on React project because of webpack

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

The error is the following: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type
It is shown for the svg and css files when the application is compiled in Angular with the package installed and called on it. In React I can use the package and works fine.
I have the following in the webpack.config.js of the package:

```js
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
                use: ['url-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
```